# How to access internal web services from windows azure with restriction IP and port

Tags: azure

We have a existing application to be migrated to the windows azure.
Currently, it will access another web services in other network, and the firewall in front of the web service, it will trust the IP of it and open the port only for that application.

Which IP should I trust after migrated to Windows Azure? or other approach suggested?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: We enhanced the web service to allow mutual certificate authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Currently Windows Azure does not offer a fixed IP address, so any IP based filter would be subject to potential risk if the IP address should change (which it can without notice).

I would recommend you explore either leveraging the service bus to create a peer-to-peer connection between the services, or possibly Azure Connect (an ipsec based VPN style connection).

Comment: So, I need to modify my web service application to use service bus? or install Azure Connect on the server host that web service?

Comment: If you need the kind of point to point connection you're after, yes. If its a WCF service, it may be as simple as adding a referrence to the Azure AppFabric servic bus namespace and changing the bindings. I can't speak to steps for setting up connect as I haven't had the opportunity to play with it (yet).